# Vertical text in Dia

Tags: diagram, dia

How can I create a vertical arrow with text (in vertical position) in Dia? Creating an arrow without text it trivial obviously, but I couldn't figure out how to make the text vertical.

Or if you could recommend an alternative Linux software for diagrams then I would also be grateful. I need eventually to generate an eps output.

Answer (score 7):

There's a YouTube video explaining text rotation in Dia:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_MkltZxFHs

Comment: You should give a brief summary whenever answering a question with an external link.

Comment: Actually, that's pretty useless. The video shows use of the outline tool. To get filled text, you have to set 'Draw background' to 'Yes', and then set a fill colour. But the background isn't correctly defined - a 'O', for example, is completely filled.

Comment: @EML Thanks for the hint. This happens in my installation, too. With most systemfonts, though, you won't get the fillings, but sadly I get text-distortion when it's rotated. [Issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dia/-/issues/465) for that is 2 weeks old could already be available in newer [builds](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dia/-/merge_requests/80).